# I am trying to use shift() on pandas dataframe, but it is not working as I expect

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

Original Dataframe:

[image]

Dafatrame after `df.shift(1, axis=1)`:

[image]

I expected a shift of only one column, not two.

Comment: Can you provide the dataframe (not the screenshot)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: {Timestamp('2020-03-02 00:00:00'): {100585.0: 0.0, 97167.0: 900.0}, Timestamp('2020-03-03 00:00:00'): {100585.0: 0.0, 97167.0: 900.0}, Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'): {100585.0: 0.0, 97167.0: 900.0}, Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00'): {100585.0: 0, 97167.0: 0}}

Answer (score 1):

Using @Olivier's sample data:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([102, 101, 104, 110, 104, 105])
df = pandas.concat([df, df+10, df+20, df+30], axis=1)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# this is actually what you have there - discrepancy in types with first column Vs the second one:

df['a']=df['a'].astype(int)
df['b']=df['b'].astype(float)
df['c']=df['c'].astype(float)
df['d']=df['d'].astype(float)

>>> print(df.shift(1, axis=1))

    a   b      c      d
0 NaN NaN  112.0  122.0
1 NaN NaN  111.0  121.0
2 NaN NaN  114.0  124.0
3 NaN NaN  120.0  130.0
4 NaN NaN  114.0  124.0
5 NaN NaN  115.0  125.0

# Mitigation:

df=df.astype(float)

>>> print(df.shift(1, axis=1))

    a      b      c      d
0 NaN  102.0  112.0  122.0
1 NaN  101.0  111.0  121.0
2 NaN  104.0  114.0  124.0
3 NaN  110.0  120.0  130.0
4 NaN  104.0  114.0  124.0
5 NaN  105.0  115.0  125.0
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting about the discrepancy in types with first column Vs the second one.

Comment: Yup, the point is - you need to fit the columns in the same, or analogical column dtype, while shifting

Answer (score 0):

Posting code is indeed easier.
Please consider this code as an example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([102, 101, 104, 110, 104, 105])
df = pandas.concat([df, df+10, df+20, df+30], axis=1)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(df)

print(df.shift(1, axis=1))
```

output:

```
     a    b    c    d
0  102  112  122  132
1  101  111  121  131
2  104  114  124  134
3  110  120  130  140
4  104  114  124  134
5  105  115  125  135
    a      b      c      d
0 NaN  102.0  112.0  122.0
1 NaN  101.0  111.0  121.0
2 NaN  104.0  114.0  124.0
3 NaN  110.0  120.0  130.0
4 NaN  104.0  114.0  124.0
5 NaN  105.0  115.0  125.0
```